# Why do I get identical MSE, MAE, DAC from different GARCH specification?

Tags: forecasting, garch, mse, mae

I estimated 5 different garch models using `rugarch` package as:

```
spec1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = T), 
                distribution.model = "norm", fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04))
spec2 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = T), 
                distribution.model = "std", fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04, omega = 0))
spec3 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = T), 
                distribution.model = "ged", fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04, omega = 0))
spec4 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = T), 
                distribution.model = "sstd", fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04, omega = 0))
spec5 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = T), 
                distribution.model = "nig", fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04, omega = 0)).
norfitt <- ugarchfit(spec1, ret, out.sample = 250, solver = "solnp", 
                    fit.control = list(stationarity = 1), rec.int = "all")
stdfitt <- ugarchfit(spec2, ret, out.sample = 250, solver = "solnp", 
                fit.control = list(stationarity = 1), rec.int = "all")
gefitt <- ugarchfit(spec3, ret, out.sample = 250, solver = "solnp", 
               fit.control = list(stationarity = 1), rec.int = "all")
sstdfitt <- ugarchfit(spec4, ret, out.sample = 250, solver = "solnp", 
                 fit.control = list(stationarity = 1), rec.int = "all")
nigfitt <- ugarchfit(spec5, ret, out.sample = 250, solver = "solnp", 
                fit.control = list(stationarity = 1), rec.int = "all").
garn.fcst = ugarchforecast(norfitt, n.roll=100, n.ahead=1)
garst.fcst = ugarchforecast(stdfitt, n.roll=100, n.ahead=1)
garsst.fcst = ugarchforecast(sstdfitt, n.roll=100, n.ahead=1)
garged.fcst = ugarchforecast(gefitt, n.roll=100, n.ahead=1)
garnig.fcst = ugarchforecast(nigfitt, n.roll=100, n.ahead=1)
```

And then:

```
fcst.list = list(garn=garn.fcst,
             garst=garst.fcst,
             garsst=garsst.fcst,
             garged=garged.fcst,
             garnig=garnig.fcst)
fpm.mat = sapply(fcst.list, fpm)
fpm.mat
```

Is it normal that I get exactly the same result?

```
as:  garn        garst       garsst      garged      garnig     
MSE 4.98334e-05 4.98334e-05 4.98334e-05 4.98334e-05 4.98334e-05
MAE 0.00549423  0.00549423  0.00549423  0.00549423  0.00549423 
DAC 0.5544554   0.5544554   0.5544554   0.5544554   0.5544554
```

Answer (score 2):

You have fixed the conditional mean model by specifying `fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 0.6038, ma1 = -0.6701, mu = 2e-04)`. Since the forecast accuracy measures you are using measure the accuracy of the conditional mean forecasts, no wonder you are getting the same result; your conditional mean model is always the same. What is different among the different specifications is the conditional variance model, but you are not measuring its performance.

Comment: thanks! and how do I measure conditional variance performace? I have not found yet which R-function to use

Comment: Measuring the fit of conditional variance is nontrivial. Actually, most of the papers I have seen do not do that at all. But see Andersen, T.G. & T. Bollerslev (1998) Answering the skeptics: Yes, standard volatility models do provide accurate forecasts. *International Economic Review*, **39** (4), 885–905 for a methodology.

Comment: @Alessandro, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?